# Permission denied change in General setting for admin user - Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Hope for everyone a good day

My admin account for odoo changed his access right for no reason
when i click in anything in "General setting" it gives me :

> Odoo Warning - Validation Error 
>   The operation cannot be completed,
>   probably due to the following:
>   - deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
>   - creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
>
> [object with reference: Users - res.users]

in the terminal it gives me such this command:

```
2018-12-16 14:37:40,087 20622 INFO CMS odoo.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "base_config_settings" ("id", "fail_counter", "module_google_drive", "company_share_product", "company_id", "module_base_import", "module_inter_company_rules", "module_share", "auth_signup_uninvited", "module_portal", "module_google_calendar", "group_multi_currency", "group_multi_company", "auth_signup_template_user_id", "group_product_variant", "alias_domain", "module_auth_oauth", "auth_signup_reset_password", "company_share_partner", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('base_config_settings_id_seq'), 0, false, true, 1, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, 10, '0', 'gmail.com', false, true, true, 12, 12, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id
```

i tried to update the modules -d -u all
i found only one warning

```
2018-12-16 11:34:45,152 3972 WARNING CMS odoo.modules.loading: The transient model base.config.settings (base.config.settings) should not have explicit access rules!
```

would any one help me, i using odoo version 10

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace or that error? And the code of your new model would also help to track down the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in field auth_signup_template_user

when i run the query in pgadmin to figure where is the bad line .. it was incorrect value = 10 is not sit with other table

field location 
In Debug mood > Setting > Technical > Parameters > System Parameters

Stander value = 5
in my case it was 10 .. so when i returned the value the error message in general setting disappeared

Thanks YOU all

Comment: sure you helped me, but i reached before you .. i appreciate your time and your work

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the terminal log at least 15-20 lines above from this >> 018-12-16 14:37:40,087 20622 INFO CMS odoo.sql_db: bad query:....

See the py file and the line number from where the error is thrown